# How to save data in controls before the session expires

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to save data in controls when the user session is about to expire. I wrote the code in 
session_end in global.asax file. But its not working when user is idle for longer period the session is being expired but data is not save. Which event to do handled is it right if we write our code in session_end event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute server side code just before the asp.net session variable expires?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883661/how-to-execute-server-side-code-just-before-the-asp-net-session-variable-expires).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be tricky at this time ....

I personally followed few step to accomplish it ...

1. Add a **base** page
2. Add a key `IsActive` on session variable to check session expiration.
3. Initialize value in `IsActive` when  user log in ..
4. `Override OnLoad` function of page class
5. add a function to check session value is about to expire or not
6. if page expiring then insert value into a database tempDB table

   ```
   public abstract class BasePage : Page
   {
       protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       {
           CheckIsSessionExpired();
           //The base method must invoke after CheckIsSessionExpired
           base.OnLoad(e);
       }

       private void CheckIsSessionExpired()
       {
           //Handling Session Expire                  
           //Any other case if session expired then it must redirect to LogOut page
           if (Session["IsActive"]==null)
           {
               TempBLL.InsertIntotempTable("some data");
               Responne.Redirect(SessionExpiredPage);
           }
       }
   }
   ```